# Unable to import java class file into jsp

Tags: jsp, java-me, midp

I'm using the upload_image code by [Jason Woods](http://moo2u2.com/projects/midlet_phone_uploader.html) for my project. After compiling the java files with changes in URL and uploading both class and java files on the server, I get an error in the upload.jsp file. It fails to import the two class files viz. ImageDataHandler and UploadedImage. How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your JSP:

```
<%@ page import="PackageName.ClassName"%>
```

Comment: The import already exists <%@ page import="javax.xml.parsers.*, 
               org.xml.sax.*,
               org.xml.sax.helpers.*,
               java.io.*,
               java.util.Vector,
               java.util.Iterator,
               ImageDataHandler,
               UploadedImage" %>